# How does the binary NOT (~) operator work?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, gml

I am quite new to programming and i have been trying to learn some basic binary, but there is still one thing that i don't quite understand. It's the rules regarding the NOT operator.

lets say i wan't to calculate this: `62&~29`

```
62 = 111110
29 = 011101
```

now the result as far as i understand should be this:

```
100011 = 35
```

but the result i get from the code is 34.

So my question is: what is happening with the last value? Why is it not being added to 34?

Hope someone can explain it to me :D

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~` is **not** the *not* operator, it is the *bitwise complement* operator.

It takes the bit pattern of the operand, and converts all 0 bits to 1 bits and all 1 bits to 0 bits.

The effect it has on a numeric value will depend on the *complement* convention that your implementation uses, and the number of bits used to represent that type.

In your specific example, `62&~29` is evaluated as `62&(~29)` which is `111110&(~011101)` which is `111110&a100010` which is `100010` which is `34`. Here I'm being pedantic and am using `a` to stand in for a number of 1 bits, so the number of bits equals the width of your type.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense. Thanks so much for your explanation :)

Comment: ~1 is actually -2 in two's complement.

Answer (score 1):

```
29    --> 011101
not29 --> 100010 (turn 1s into 0 and vice-versa)

62       --> 111110
not29    --> 100010
62&not29 --> 100010 (1 if and only if both are 1, otherwise 0)
```

How did you get 35?

Comment: I got 35 because i didn't really know how the & works, but i see now what i got wrong. I converted 0 to 1 even though both wasn't ones or zeroes. Thanks for the help :)